# Different signal length for each batch

Tags: keras, signal-processing, generator

I wonder if it Is it possible to have a different signal length for each batch when training a model.

- Batch 1 : all signals of length 1000
- Batch 2 : all signals of length 2000
- Batch 3 : all signals of length 3000

and so on.

Or should one use padding/truncating instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common approach is to do padding or truncation. However, your idea of using batches of different lengths is already explored in [this paper from Google](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10467.pdf) (see section 3.2).

Comment: Thanks @Oriol B!